# Set SelectedItem in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am adding `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` to `datagridview` column and want to set the first item as `selectedItem / selectedIndex`, but there are some examples to achieve this if only `datasource` is assigned to it, but I don't want to use datasource

Here is my code

```
 Dim col As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

 For Each r As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
     col.Items.Add(r("Months"))
 Next

 Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
 row.CreateCells(dgv)
 row.Cells(0) = col

 dgv.Rows.Add(row)
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about your question or i wonder where is the question. Is the code working?

Comment: yes code is working, and I can see all the added items in combobox, but 1st item is not selected, and the question is how to set the 1st item of combobox as selected item ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with altered DataGridView columns, you want to work with the Value property.  Add this line of code somewhere before `row.Cells(0) = col`:

```
col.Value = col.Items(0)
```

Comment: not working, shows `'Items' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'`

Comment: @Ahmed Oops.  Forgot, you'd have to cast the cell back to DataGridViewComboBoxCell, or do the same operation on `Dim col`.  See my edited answer.